# Self service password change with TOTP confirmation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Based on samples available on Github (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/totp) I have implemented policies for enabling TOTP MFA.

Now, when the user wants to change his password (not reset via "Forgot your password?") I would like to introduce TOTP verification step if he has TOTP enabled.

**First attempt:**

```
<UserJourney Id="PasswordChange">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSigninOnly-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
      <JourneyList>
        <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="TotpFactor-Verify" />
      </JourneyList>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>

  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
</UserJourneys>
```

Fails immediately when I try to upload policy via Azure Portal with error:

> Orchestration step order "2" in user journey "PasswordChange" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "{tenant}" is followed by a claims provider selection step and must be a claims exchange, but it is of type "InvokeSubJourney"

**Second attempt:**

Commented `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId` ValidationTechnicalProfile in `LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId`:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account Password Change</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId">
      <DisplayName>Change password (username)</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oldPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive-PasswordChange" />
        <!-- <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" /> -->
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

UserJourney:

```
<UserJourney Id="PasswordChange">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSigninOnly-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
      <JourneyList>
        <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="TotpFactor-Verify" />
      </JourneyList>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>

  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

As you can see I added OrchestrationStep 4 of type ClaimsExchange. It runs `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId`.

I can successfully go through this journey without any errors, however password is not updated.

Comment: Password claim can’t go to the next orchestration step, it’s protected. It should be written using a validation technical profile from a selfAsserted technical profile that collects the new password.

Comment: Thanks. That was my guess after taking a look at this sample - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/unit-tests/blob/main/claims/Claim_UserInputTypes_All.xml - where claim with UserInputType of Password wasn't returned in a token.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by reverting changes made in `LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId` TechnicalProfile (so basically uncommenting ValidationTechnical profile I have commented before) and with the following `UserJourney`.

```
<UserJourney Id="PasswordChange">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSigninOnly-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges />
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
      <JourneyList>
        <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="TotpFactor-Verify" />
      </JourneyList>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordChangeUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>

  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

As you can see, here, as a second step, I had to add an empty step of type `ClaimsExchange`. It should be always skipped, as only available sign in method of step 1 is local account so objectId should always be present.

I can successfully upload such policy. It works without any errors and changes user password.

However, this empty step looks strange.

Comment: can I ask where you got "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSigninOnly-Email" from, or what it looks like? I'm having trouble implementing a similar function, but mine falls over at the check for string authentication devices.

Comment: It was the same as standard `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` from one of the starter packs but with: `setting.showSignupLink`=False and `setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation`=none. Anyway, as there were problems with keeping session between `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` and `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSigninOnly-Email` I rolled back to using `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email`. You can find content of `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSigninOnly-Email` here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766307/share-session-between-two-different-but-very-similar-technicalprofiles.